# Do I need to install SQL Server Compact Edition on all client's desktops?

Tags: wpf, sql-server-ce

I am developping a WPF desktop application, that I deliver to my users by a setup project with Visual Studio (2008, .Net 3.5). This application uses a local database, whose type is SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5.

My question is : do the users have to install SQL Server Compact Edition in addition to my application, or ideally is it possible to deliver all required DLL for SQL Server Compact Edition with my application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql Server is not just a set of DLLs, but Microsoft makes it easy to deploy.  Check out this [blog](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html).

Comment: Many thanks, that tutorial worked for me. I just adapted a little it for working with SQL CE 3.5 (this tuto is for 4.0). I was missing the edition of the app.config file (with the increment of version for not taking the assembly in the GAC), that Visual Studio don't make automatically.