# WPF / EF4 Application Installer

Tags: wpf, entity-framework-4, installation, windows-installer

I have written a WPF Application with a datalayer using Entity Framework 4 (EF4, using SQL Server, **not** Compact Edition). How can I ensure that everything the App needs gets installed at the customer? Is there a standard way to install EF4 with a Windows Installer?

---

EDIT: found an article about that problem: [Using SQL Server Compact 4.0 with Desktop Private Deployment and a Setup project (MSI) (part 2)](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html). I might change some stuff (like autokey creation) and use CE

Similar question: [Do I need to install SQL Server Compact Edition on all client's desktops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651328/do-i-need-to-install-sql-server-compact-edition-on-all-clients-desktops)

maybe interisting for people doing something similar: [SQLCE is a compact database that is click once deployable...](http://www.coderenaissance.com/2010/04/using-sqlce-with-entity-framework-and.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your program is compiled, there is no need to 'install entity framework' on client machines.  Entity framework is just a framework to aid you with using SQL while coding.

Perhaps what you're asking is how to install your application and set it up to work with the database?  Then:

1. Using an installer program, move the files over for your application and do any setup.
2. Install sql server, and run your *.edmx.sql script that is automatically generated by your model.
3. Connect the two by modifying your app.config file.

Comment: I want to avoid step two on the clients machine. On my development workstation everything is installed fine, but what if I want to distribute it over the net or give it to a friend. Does he/she need to install SQL Server or is it possible to run the compiled app just with a database file and dlls?

Comment: You'll want to use a .mdf (Access) file, then.  It's a bit more difficult and slower, but still fine.  See here:  http://blog.gerke-preussner.de/2010/11/model-first-entity-framework-with-mdf-database-files-in-app_data/